# Incorrect VBO for mesh: some triangles are connected and shouldn't [2D]

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm generating my VBO with this code

```
    int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
    int PIXEL_PER_VERTEX = 4;
    int CAVERN_TEXTURE_WIDTH = 1024;
    int CAVERN_TEXTURE_HEIGHT = 512;

    final int vertexCount = ((SCREEN_WIDTH / PIXEL_PER_VERTEX) +1 ) * 2;
    final float[] bufferDataLowerCave = new float[vertexCount * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE];

    for(int i=0; i < vertexCount; i += 2) {
        bufferDataLowerCave[i * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = PIXEL_PER_VERTEX * i / 2.f;
        bufferDataLowerCave[i * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = 200;
        bufferDataLowerCave[i * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_U] = ( (float) PIXEL_PER_VERTEX * i / 2.f) / SCREEN_WIDTH;
        bufferDataLowerCave[i * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_V] = 0.f;

        bufferDataLowerCave[(i + 1 ) * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = PIXEL_PER_VERTEX * i / 2;
        bufferDataLowerCave[(i + 1 ) * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = 0;
        bufferDataLowerCave[(i + 1 ) * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_U] = ( (float) PIXEL_PER_VERTEX * i / 2.f) / SCREEN_WIDTH;
        bufferDataLowerCave[(i + 1 ) * CavernBoundMesh.VERTEX_SIZE + CavernBoundMesh.TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_V] = 0.5f;
    }
```

I'm drawing the mesh(centred in the origin) with TRIANGLE_STRIP.

Sorry, no openGL code since i'm using an engine(AndEngine). But if you really need, i can try to track it down..
[image: Incorrect mesh displayed]

As you can see in the image the last 2 vertices are connected with a vertex in the origin.I debugged the creation of the VBO and this is the first and the last vertices

```
//X       Y       U        V
[0.0,    200.0,  0.0,     0.0,
 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,
 4.0,    200.0,  0.0050,  0.0,
 4.0,    0.0,    0.0050,  0.5,
 8.0,    200.0,  0.01,    0.0,
 8.0,    0.0,    0.01,    0.5,
 12.0,   200.0,  0.015,   0.0,
 12.0,   0.0,    0.015,   0.5,
 16.0,   200.0,  0.02,    0.0,
 16.0,   0.0,    0.02,    0.5
 [..]
 780.0,  200.0,  0.975,   0.0,
 780.0,  0.0,    0.975,   0.5,
 784.0,  200.0,  0.98,    0.0,
 784.0,  0.0,    0.98,    0.5,
 788.0,  200.0,  0.985,   0.0,
 788.0,  0.0,    0.985,   0.5,
 792.0,  200.0,  0.99,    0.0,
 792.0,  0.0,    0.99,    0.5,
 796.0,  200.0,  0.995,   0.0,
 796.0,  0.0,    0.995,   0.5]
```

This is the vertex shader that i used

```
uniform mat4 u_modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform float u_elapsedSeconds;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_textureCoordinates;

varying vec2 v_textureCoordinates;

void main(void)
{
    v_textureCoordinates = a_textureCoordinates;
    vec4 temp_position = u_modelViewProjectionMatrix * a_position;

    float variation = 0.3*sin((u_elapsedSeconds + 1.5 * temp_position.x))*(1.0 + temp_position.y);
    temp_position.y += variation;

    gl_Position = temp_position;
}
```

I'm very new to this stuff, so i do not know well the specifications and how it works, but i can't really understand what's going on to generate this strange effect. Can you help me out?

EDIT1:

i made some more tests..
Even with a standard vertex and fragment shader that just sets the position and the colour fetching it from a textures it gives weird results.

EDIT2:
A few more images, this time just with the 2 standard vert and frag shader for position and texture colour (This images are taken from a Tablet, while the first is from a phone)

[image: wrong image 1]
[image: 2° wrong image]
[image: 3° wrong image]
[image: my favourite wrong image]

Comment: Looks like you are drawing too many primitives and seeing artifacts from that. How many triangles are you telling it to draw? You should tell it to draw `n-2` triangles if you give it `n` vertices in a triangle strip.

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong. If you use 2D you should use QUADS(two triangles that make a rectange) then draw textures to the quads. Don't use so many triangles.

Comment: @dragostis using a triangle strip is probably the most efficient way of doing this since it will efficiently reuse the vertices instead of duplicating them since he is not using indexed lists.

Comment: @Dervall Yes, you're chiefly right.

Comment: @dragostis i tried to implement vertices list, but 1) the engine is not designed for them, i ended up rewriting a lot of classes and it wasn't even working. I stopped losing time on it since 2)it would consume more memory than this way since i would reuse only few vertices.
Actually i don't think openGL ES 2 supports drawing Quads, in addition i need many vertices since the mesh will change a lot, and without them it would look very "pixelate".
I tried running the App with different PIXEL_PER_VERTEX value: each one gives totally different results.. What can i do to prevent this?

Comment: Your implementation is not good and it is definitely not reliable. I suggest you use another engine. Try [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) for size. It's very neat and easy to use. There's even a book on the matter. To change the subject, from what I see you are trying to achieve hills reminiscent of those from the iOS game Tiny Wings. If the type of effect you are trying to achieve is not working for you, I suggest you start a new question and explain what you are trying to achieve with you app.

Comment: @dragostis i don't get what is the relation between my error and "I suggest you use another engine". I'm in an early phase of development, so maybe changing engine is not that problem, but i don't really know why would you suggest it, without even asking what my current engine does (btw, the developer of AndEngine has been hired by zynga and his engine has been used for a game of theirs, so it's not an "amateur" engine) I'm trying to create a cavern (boundaries up and down) where a character can fly in between.All the computation of the correct position of the cavern happens in the vert shader

Comment: Because it's very hard to understand why you used 200 vertices...

Comment: @dragostis The options i thought about are 2: 1)take the cave mesh still, and move the player and the camera. This would bring to an infinite mesh(since the level is dynamically generated) 2)Take the cave, the player and the camera still, and update the cave meshes in order to fake the movement. In order to do this i need many vertices, otherwise you will see it flickering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you are specifying the wrong number of primitives to your drawing code since the vertices themselves look alright to me. When you do a drawing call to openGL or any other 3D primitive drawing you do not specify the number of vertices to draw but the number of *primitives*. A primitive in you case is a triangle.

Since it's a triangle strip you're drawing it's always `numberOfVertices - 2` primitives in your call. If it were a list of triangles it would have been `numberOfVertices/3`, and for a triangle fan it's `numberOfVertices - 2` again.

Since you are probably specifying more triangles to be drawn than it has data to draw for, it's probably using some default `(0,0,0,0)` which explains that it is trying to draw two degenerate triangles in the bottom left corner that is also referencing the texture coordinate `0,0`. This also makes sense since there isn't even a vertex that has the position `0,0` and the T/U `0,0` in your list, so the last vertex must be some default value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i'll go throught the code and try to find the part that specify how many primitives are draw. The only problem left is that while making some tests happened that the mesh displayed where far more random that the one in the original post. I'll screenshot them and edit the original post

Comment: Randomness is to be expected when you draw too much stuff than you have data for.

Comment: hahah, yeah, i suppose! Btw i just checked how the rendering is done, and the code uses '''glDrawArrays'''. The specifies say "count: Specifies the number of indices to be rendered." http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml
Should it use numberOfVertices - 2 in my case? Right now i'm passing numberOfVertices

Comment: Yes, `numberOfVertices-2` is correct for a triangle strip. By the way, if it uses indices, are you giving it an index list as well?

Comment: No, i'm not. I have a partial implementation with index, but i never got it working, since 1) i'm a noob in openGl and thus i had no idea why it weren't working 2) i thought that it was more memory efficient to just use Triangl_Strip: i use around 200 useful vertices on a side of the rectangle and 200 on the other as a support for drawing with Triangle_Strip, if i used indices i would need 200 usefull + 2 support + 200 *3 indices (3 indices per triangle, per 200 triangles). BTW i just tried with numberOfVertices -2 and i get the same result...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it.

After trying libgdx (i don't really like it, it seams a lot of utility functions are missing, and i haven't really grasped the concept behind it, eg how it treats textures, how manage entities, etc..) and implemented a really small renderer in native language with jni and also setted up cocos-2d-x (but haven't tried it, since i first played a bit with the jni code and wrote the above mentioned renderer) i fell back to AndEngine.

I succesfully managed to implement a mesh with VBO and also a IBO, but finally i solved my problem by duplicating (adding 2 identical vertices) at the start and the end of the VBO, so that the additional triangles are degenerated and are not drawn. So, that's most a workaround, but as long as it works..