# Is Triangle_Strip supposed to wrap?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm facing a problem i worked around some time ago ([Incorrect VBO for mesh: some triangles are connected and shouldn't [2D]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161633/incorrect-vbo-for-mesh-some-triangles-are-connected-and-shouldnt-2d)), and since my shader have become more complex and different problems connected to this arose, i need to solve it at its foundations!

This is the VBO content:

```
[0.0, 0.0,
 0.0, 240.0,

 10.0, 0.0,
 10.0, 240.0,

 20.0, 0.0,
 20.0, 240.0,

 30.0, 0.0,
 30.0, 240.0

 and so on up to

 1190.0, 0.0,
 1190.0, 240.0,

 1200.0, 0.0,
 1200.0, 240.0,

 1210.0, 0.0,
 1210.0, 240.0]
```

So the array length is 244 point * 2 coordinate = 488 elements.

This is the opengl trace of a frame

```
glClearColor(red = 0,100000, green = 0,100000, blue = 0,100000, alpha = 1,000000)
glClear(mask = 16384)
glEnable(cap = GL_BLEND)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 2)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = 1)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 8, ptr = 0x0)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 1, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.004166667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
glUniform1i(location = 5, x = 0)
glUniform4f(location = 3, x = 0,000000, y = 0,000000, z = 1,000000, w = 0,500000)
glUniform1f(location = 4, x = 2,491089)
glUniform1f(location = 0, x = 1780,000000)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 2, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [-100.0, 40.0, 260.0, 430.0, 165.6131, 122.20027, 247.55757, 189.05222, 680.0, 880.0, -268.66666, -268.66666, 126.442535, 1.7712338, 160.0, 160.0])
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 486)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 1)
glDisable(cap = GL_BLEND)
glEnable(cap = GL_BLEND)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 3)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = 1)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 8, ptr = 0x0)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 1, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.004166667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
glUniform1i(location = 5, x = 0)
glUniform4f(location = 3, x = 0,000000, y = 0,500000, z = 1,000000, w = 0,500000)
glUniform1f(location = 4, x = 2,491089)
glUniform1f(location = 0, x = 1780,000000)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 2, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [-60.0, 150.0, 330.0, 550.0, -71.13025, -193.20978, -11.679321, -223.35025, 740.0, 990.0, -268.66666, -268.66666, -394.54395, -270.3169, -160.0, -160.0])
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 486)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 1)
glDisable(cap = GL_BLEND)
eglSwapBuffers
```

My shader is a bit long and complex, but it does nothing but move along the Y axis the vertices that have the Y component different from 0. The uniform values are correct, and the shader works correctly.

When i render with TRIANGLE_STRIP the screen shows lines that connect the first vertex (0,0) with the last one (1210, ???) (??? because my shader moves it, and it is not at 240. I know where it is, and it is where it should be, but it constantly varies.)

[image: TRIANGLE_STRIP rendering glitch]

Rendering with LINE_STRIP just confirms the problem.

[image: LINE_STRIP rendering glitch]

So, is this the expected behaviour of TRIANGLE_STRIP? Or is something wrong? Reading the opengl specification it seams that it shouldn't wrap, but it does (in different devices, so it's not a specific driver issue)

Comment: nope, TRIANGLE_STRIP will render triangles from the first 3 vertices to the last 3 vertices sent. maybe your array was not initialized correctly making the last vertex = [0 0] ?

Comment: No, the values posted here are taken from a debug breakpoint. glBufferData buffers the amount of data expected: 4 * 488 bytes, so the vbo on VRAM is correct.. Any other idea? Can you tell if the rendering calls are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally found the solution.

I was passing the length of my array minus 2 as the count of vertex to draw. The error was that my vertex array holds both X and Y coordinates, so it was actually long twice the number of primitive to draw.

I now use array.length / 2, and all works correctly.

Btw, when I found it out, I thought performances would increase. Instead it didn't happen.